# Angular UI Bootstrap: *Instead* of bootstrap3's js, or in *addition* to it?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

The Github readme is not entirely clear on this point... Are they alternatives, or, meant to work together?

Comment: Actually the home page says: Dependencies
This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on Twitter Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies are:

AngularJS (minimal version 1.0.4 or 1.1.2)
Bootstrap CSS @bjorke - do you see how we could clarify further?

Comment: Thanks Pawel for making this tool! As you can see in my comments below, I was unclear on the recommendation to remove the standard bootstrap js -- that it interferes(?). I think the word "replacement" is key. I was also a bit confused, I think, because the demo page doesn't include all the available directives (so my existing page, which had used bootstrap tabs, now failed, until I updated it). Thanks again!'

Comment: Oops, somehow I missed the tabs sample! My mistake. Working great now, thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UI Bootstrap is a replacement for the bootstrap JS portion it is clearly stated but not on the main page.

> Native AngularJS (Angular) directives for Twitter's Bootstrap. Small
>   footprint (5kB gzipped!), no 3rd party JS dependencies (jQuery,
>   bootstrap JS) required!  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Thanks Shaun... I read that too, what was unclear IMO is that the directives _replace_ the std bootstrap functions, since the sample page only shows new extra directives like the calendar - not Angular revisions of std ones. The startup steps describe downloading the js & adding ui.bootstrap to my module,  but not "remove old bootstrap js" - which I shall do!

Comment: Yup think you got it right now, Jens answer below gives a bit more detail too.

Answer (score 4):

Dean Sofer on the subject: http://deansofer.com/posts/view/20/AngularJS-and-Bootstrap

Think that explains it rather well... And give you insight into "Why" as well...

> We have 2 projects: the AngularUI Bootstrap project which is recreating everything in pure AngularJS code, and removes the Bootstrap.js dependency. Then we have the new Angular-Strap which simply wraps the existing Bootstrap.js creating additional dependencies and imposing a fairly opinionated templating scheme.

And some links to the to mentioned projects for completeness:

- Angular UI Bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
- Angular Strap: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

What side to agree with is up to you.

Comment: I think the new version of angular strap doesnt need jquery and bootstrap js anymore. So the differences between those 2 options become....less clear?